# Can't press button with promise using playwright and java

Tags: java, automation, ui-automation, playwright, playwright-java

I'm trying to write automation using playwright and java on login page.
the login button has some kind of promise and when i click it - nothing happens , i'm not entering the page i need to.

i tried using different ways of clicking or pressing 'enter' and doesn't work

screenshot of the button :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIvrD.png)

here is my code trying to press it :

```
    
String buttonSelector = "#userLoginForm > div:nth-child(4) > button";

page.dispatchEvent(buttonSelector,"click");
```

i also tried the following code:

```
page.waitForNavigation(() -> {
                page.click(buttonSelector);
            });
```

the button is pressed but not really , not navigated to the next page . like the action didn't work

Comment: You can try using different selector String buttonSelector = "button[b2b-load-button='Loading...'][value='submit']";
page.click(buttonSelector);

Comment: And also you can try adding 2 seconds sleep before click. Thread.sleep(2000); 
page.click(buttonSelector);   Anyways this(page.click()) method should handle the promise internally and wait for any navigation or action associated with the click.

Comment: both of those helped thanks

Comment: perfect. Good to go!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the fact that the web element is a button with the label 'Log in' and try the below code.

```java
page.getByRole(AriaRole.BUTTON, new Page.GetByRoleOptions().setName("Log in")).click();
```

As already mentioned, the `click` method waits for the button to be actionable prior to taking an action.

To know more about the `getByRole` method, please check [this](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-locator#locator-get-by-role).

Comment: yeah, i know this . probably a sleep or pressing the button with the selector helped for some reason.